# How to check if string exists on external page with JavsScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check a page (on the same domain) for a specific string and then execute something accordingly. How can I go about this in JavaScript (with jQuery loaded)?

A (maybe too much) simplified schematic:

```
url = "pageToLoad.php"

if(StringOnPage(url) == TRUE){
    // Do a bunch of stuff
}else{
    // Do nothing
}
```

Now how would I construct `StringOnPage()` ideally? I made several attempts with jQuery's `.load`  and `.ajax`, I even tried to load it into a hidden container. There must be a way to load the page into a string and check for an expression or something without all the html hacks.

The page is just an HTML populated file. Basically I need to find a text in a DOM element.

Comment: how is this string placed in the page? HTML? just plain text? in JSON? can you be a bit clearer?

Comment: @Joseph Just plain text in HTML. Basically it's just text in a DOM element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the page via AJAX as a plain string and then simply check if the string you are looking for is somewhere in the string you got from your AJAX call:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    if(data.indexOf('whatever') != -1) {
        // do a bunch of stuff
    }
}, 'text');
```

Of course you could also use `'html'` instead of `'text'`; then `data` is a jQuery object containing the DOM of the page you just loaded.

Comment: Maybe a lot to ask, but I got this far already. How would I integrate this into my structure?

Comment: You cannot use it synchronously. Everything that relies on the result of the `if` from your question needs to go into that callback.