# How can I have a Tampermonkey userscript play a sound when a specific word appears on a page?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

In a chat room, when someone pastes a certain word into the chat I want the browser to make a noise to alert me.

It seems like Tampermonkey should be able to do this, but I don't know how to start and [searching turns up few, and inapplicable results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript%20play%20a%20sound%20when%20a%20word%20appears).
(This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226928/play-a-sound-in-js-when-some-text-appear-on-the-screen) seems close but the answer just plays a sound every 5 seconds no matter what!)

How can a userscript alert when a target word appears via AJAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a `MutationObserver` to watch for the target word.  Then use HTML5 `Audio` to play the desired sound.

This **complete working script** watches for the text "just now" and plays a mellifluous tune when that phrase appears:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Play sound when word appears on a page
// @include  https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces */

//-- Set the watched terms using the awesome power of regex.
var watchRegx = /\bjust now\b/i;
var alrtSound = new Audio ("data:audio/mp3;base64,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");

//-- Customize this next for your page or get lazy and use "body".
var cntnrNode = document.querySelector ("#mainArea");
if (typeof cntnrNode === "undefined")   console.error ("TM: Container node not found.");
else {
    var wordObsrv = new MutationObserver (alertOnWord);
    wordObsrv.observe (document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true} );
}
function alertOnWord (mutationRecords) {
    mutationRecords.forEach (muttn => {
        if (muttn.type === "childList"  &&  typeof muttn.addedNodes === "object") {
            muttn.addedNodes.forEach (newNode => {
                /*-- Restrict the kinds of nodes watched for better performance
                    and/or to avoid false positives.
                */
                if (newNode.nodeName === "DIV"  ||  newNode.nodeName === "SPAN"  ||  newNode.nodeName === "P") {
                    if (watchRegx.test (newNode.textContent) ) {
                        console.log ("Found new instance of target term!");
                        alrtSound.play ();
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
}
```

Install that script using Tampermonkey, or Violentmonkey, or similar and then visit [the ***Stack Exchange Realtime*** page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime)

You will hear the sound every time a new post appears -- which is usually several times per minute.

Comment: I changed the script code and it works on Firefox. With Google Chrome and TamperMonkey it says No Script is running.

But even on Firefox, for the specific chat page I am wanting it to work on it doesn't work. It will make a noise if the word is on the page, but if it is within the chat box itself it does not. Could this be because the type of chat or webpage?

Comment: When I view the page info within the chat box it says:

Page Type: text/html
Render mode: Standards compliance mode
Text Encoding: UTF-8

Comment: @MarkC, we can't tell because you haven't provided a link to the chat.  There are several possibilities. The most likely is that the actual chat box is in an iframe.  In that case, you would set the script's `@include` to match the iframe URL. ... Anyway, that's all beyond the scope of ***this*** question as you did not provide enough info when you asked it. [Mark this question complete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) and then ask a new question, if needed. **Include either the page URL or enough information so that we can replicate the new problem EXACTLY.**

Comment: Ok, It is a private URL which I can only access by signing into a secure connection via Juno Pulse. Thank you for your help anyway.