# Playing a Sound Notification when Specific Text on Page Appears

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to figure out a way to play a sound notification whenever the phrase "2 credits" appears in the top right corner on a specific website at: https://www.submithub.com/. As it stands, that specific area of the site oscillates between "0 credits" and "2 credits" depending on if you've submitted to the site within the last few hours. Once you are able to submit again, the text changes to "2 credits."

I have also provided a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

I have been using code primarily derived from the following StackOverflow thread: [How can I have a Tampermonkey userscript play a sound when a specific word appears on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356913/how-can-i-have-a-tampermonkey-userscript-play-a-sound-when-a-specific-word-appea)

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     SubmitHub Notification
// @include  https://www.submithub.com/
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces */

//-- Set the watched terms using the awesome power of regex.
var watchRegx = /\b2 credits\b/i;
var alrtSound = new Audio ("data:audio/mp3;base64,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");

//-- Customize this next for your page or get lazy and use "body".
var cntnrNode = document.querySelector ("#mainArea");
if (typeof cntnrNode === "undefined")   console.error ("TM: Container node not found.");
else {
    var wordObsrv = new MutationObserver (alertOnWord);
    wordObsrv.observe (document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true} );
}
function alertOnWord (mutationRecords) {
    mutationRecords.forEach (muttn => {
        if (muttn.type === "childList"  &&  typeof muttn.addedNodes === "object") {
            muttn.addedNodes.forEach (newNode => {
                /*-- Restrict the kinds of nodes watched for better performance
                    and/or to avoid false positives.
                */
                if (newNode.nodeName === "DIV"  ||  newNode.nodeName === "SPAN"  ||  newNode.nodeName === "P") {
                    if (watchRegx.test (newNode.textContent) ) {
                        console.log ("Found new instance of target term!");
                        alrtSound.play ();
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
}
```

As it stands, I cannot get "2 credits" to make any notification sounds via Regex, such as shown below, but I have been able to get just "credits" to work:

```
var watchRegx = /\b2 credits\b/i;
```

Here is the HTML of the specific part of the page where "2 credits" lies on the site:

```
<span class="grey black-text lighten-2 credit-counter"><span class="remaining">2</span> credits</span>
```

The nature of the HTML indicates that this might not be as simple as using a Regex with "2 credits." Maybe there is an easy solution. Any and all advice would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So does the `if (watchRegx.test ...)` statement pass, you get the `console.log`, but the sound doesn't play? Or does it never reach the `alrtSound.play ();`? i.e. the if statement fails.

Comment: I believe that the statement fails. When I try the code with just "credits," it outputs "Found new instance of target term!" into the console. When I try "2 credits" it does not print anything to the console.

Comment: Pay attention to the `document.querySelector ("#mainArea")` and the comment above it.  You need to adapt that selector to your site.

Comment: I've tried changing the selector to different options, but to no avail. "2" never works, but "credits" still seems to work. I even tried using "remaining," the name of the span class that contains the "2." I'm not the most versed in RegEx, but maybe it handles digits differently?

Comment: I changed the RegEx code to "var watchRegx = /2 credits/;" - this may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed the RegEx code to `var watchRegx = /2 credits/;` A simple enough solution. Thanks for all the feedback

Answer (score -1):

Here, we might want to separately capture our desired substrings then replace it:

```
.+?<span class="remaining">([0-9]+)?<\/span>(.+?)<\/span>
```

Our desired digits are in this capturing group:

```
([0-9]+)
```

and the second part is in this group:

```
(.+?)
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.+?<span class="remaining">([0-9]+)?<\/span>(.+?)<\/span>/gm;
const str = `<span class="grey black-text lighten-2 credit-counter"><span class="remaining">2</span> credits</span>`;
const subst = `$1$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/112ltF/1/)

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. It definitely helps me understand the fundamentals of Regex more, too. Unfortunately, since I'm somewhat of a JavaScript novice, I've been unable to successfully apply your code to my script. I tried inserting /.+?<span class="remaining">([0-9]+)?<\/span>(.+?)<\/span>/ into var watchRegx = /\b2 credits\b/i; but to no avail